# Access static function inside class-c#

Tags: c#, oop, static

I have the below snippet took from a [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com)

```
class myfun
{
    int x;
    static int y;
    void fun()
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
    }
    static void gun()
    {
        x = 1;//An object reference error
        y = 1;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
       myfun.gun();
       //Error  1   The namespace already contains a definition for 'myfun' 
    }
}
```

Why this error says it contains a definition already?

Edit: I cross checked the other files in the same solution and found it has been used in one more class file. So one of the problem solved. The error already contains definition is resolved. But still im unclear of how to use a variable inside a static function. I can achieve it by changing it to static. but anyone can suggest alternatives for this?

What is the best approach to access a variable inside a static method?

Comment: The first problem is that `int x` is not *static*, but addressed with *static* method:  `static void gun()  {  x = 1; ...}`

Comment: Code provided in the post does not fail with that error in C# (ignoring `x = 1;` it compile just fine). Please make sure you've pasted correct code / error. See [MCVE] for guidance.

Comment: Additionally, there's no indication of *any* connection between this question and ASP.NET...

Comment: what ide version you use?

Comment: To access an instance variable, you need an *instance*. This means there has to be [an instantiation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) somewhere, like `var myInstance = new myfun();` (terrible naming you've got there btw; 1) myfun is not a function, 2) don't prefix stuff with "my", 3) use PascalCasing for class names in C#). So, each instance of `myfun` will have its own set of instance variables (`x`), while static variables (`y` in your case) are defined on type level and shared between all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *doesn't compile*:

```
class myfun
{
    int x; // <- non static, instance
    ...
    static void gun()
    {
        x = 1; // <- ...but addressed within static method
        y = 1;
    }
```

probably you should make `x` being *static*; another *issue* is that if you mean standard `main` method (like that in `C`, `C++`, `Java`) you should put it like this:

```
  // Note capitalization
  static void Main() { ... }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Please see my updated question. But how i can refer a non static variable in static method?

Comment: @user833985, your code still raise _An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'myfun.x'_

Comment: @Grundy..this answer also mentioned the same error. I am looking for a solution for the same and my earlier comment, i raised the same question of how to refer non static variable in static method?

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is you are calling X from your static method.that should throw an error there.This is a faulty function that you are trying to call from other function that calling is right but the function you are calling is faulty so it never should work.you better make X as static as well.